# Work flow for multiple developers

Tags: options, customization, configuration, development-strategy

I'm looking to streamline the development work flow for a new project that will have multiple developers involved (backend and frontend).

My biggest quandary is how best to make sure all devs have the same site settings and plugin settings.

For example, with Drupal, we can use the Features module in v7 and the (somewhat scatty but it works) configuration sync in v8.

These turn backend CMS settings into files that can be stored in the repo and imported by the dev.

With the very latest version of WordPress, what are my options when it comes to something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Git for theme code/plugins could be a good option while you can use a common db in order to be sure that you all have the same data entry.
This way you can easily update everyone local repository or review past code and you can keep relating with your collaborators without expecting different layout views and execution results.

You also don't need to change `wp-config.php` settings after the first-time(You shouldn't git it since it contains db user and pwd credentials).

Hope it helps!

Comment: We use git, but we don't share databases, as we use vagrant virtual machines. I'm not talking about the config file, I mean settings in the site that are stored in the database.